# Machine Learning with Skewed Classes in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, caret

I am looking for some suggestions on what methods are appropriate for training a dataset with a high skew in the outcome classes. The ratio of Class 0: Class 1 is about 20:1 and I am looking to maximize the accuracy for identifying Class 1 outcomes. This is similar to oft discussed topics such as cancer detection.

I have used some methods before but am trying to find if there is any comprehensive resource / suggestions that talks to the different methods for these cases. Examples of how they are applied in R (packages, etc) or with caret would be useful. It is a sparse dataset with about 100K examples of which 5000 belong to Class 1 and the rest to Class 0. Each example has about 20 features, and includes null values.

Answer (score 1):

There's a reference I use for classifying with skewed data: [Cohen, 2006](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1839342/). In it, the author describes a method for weighted over-sampling of samples, based on class prevalence in the data set. You should read the paper, but, briefly, the cost function he proposes takes the form

$$P(c)=\frac{{\rm Cost}(c)}{\max[\text{Cost}(c),\ \forall_{c}\in C]}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [AppliedPredictiveModeling](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AppliedPredictiveModeling/index.html) package, it has scripts associated with the book. Chapter 16 is about class imbalances and shows how to deal with them with `caret` and a lot of other packages.

The code for each chapter is in the `AppliedPredictiveModeling` package and, once loaded, those files can be found using the `scriptLocation` function.